# Change JQuery Row Color

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a collapsable list of elements, that has a filter at the top. However, when a user taps on the table row on iOS devices, the row becomes blue for a second. This color does not match the color scheme of my project, and so I am wondering if someone knew how to change the color. JQuery, JQuery Mobile, and the CSS file are all local to the machine.

Here is a screenshot of the issue in the iOS Simulator:

[image]

Here is a live preview of my project: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/M7LLU/

I have tried using the following with no luck:

```
.highlight {
     background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `ui-btn-active`, this class is added by jQM to any element that accommodates `a` tag.

Override `.ui-btn-active` default CSS properties followed by `!important` to force override.

```
background-color:#38c;
border-color:#38c;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #059
```

---

You can either override it to change its' color on all elements with `a` tag,

```
.ui-btn-active {
  background-color: newColor !important;
}
```

Or specifically on some *widgets*, e.g. *collapsible*.

```
.ui-collapsible .ui-btn-active {
  background-color: newColor !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GSrQ9/)**

Comment: Thanks for posting. Do you know if it is possible to change the outline color and text color when this occurs? When I use your solution, the majority of the tab changes color, however, I can't seem to change the edges from blue. Any ideas?

Comment: @JakeChasan surely you can, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I have tried the code, however, I still have a blue frame around the tab. Here is a photo of what is happening: http://jakeserver.com/Uploads/Images/23478345.png Here are the CSS Setting I am trying to use:   background-color: #d9e6ba !important;
border-color:#000000; !important;
color:#000; !important;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ffffff; !important;

Comment: @JakeChasan you're adding `;` between value and `!important`. I've updated demo with CSS code.

Comment: You are completely right. I missed that. Thank you so much for all of the help. One last quick question: is the !important tag even necessary?

Comment: @JakeChasan usually it's necessary to force override. Try removing it, if styles are applied, then it's unnecessary :)

Comment: Thanks again for all of the help today.